# Assigning jq output to bash array when json value contains spaces

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

When I do this:

```
arr=($(echo '{"crew":[{"name":"kirk"},{"name":"bones"},{"name":"mr spock"}]}' | jq -r '.crew[].name | @sh'))
```

I get:

```
echo "${arr[2]}"
mr
echo "${arr[3]}"
spock
```

However when I do this:

```
arr=("kirk" "bones" "mr spock")
```

I get this:

```
echo "${arr[2]}"
mr spock
```

Why, in the first example, is bash ignoring the quotes that each jq value is wrapped in when it creates the array?

Comment: You stripped out the quotes by using jq -r

Comment: @RamanSailopal The jq operator `@sh` escapes the output, as per the jq manual: "The input is escaped suitable for use in a command-line for a POSIX shell. If the input is an array, the output will be a series of space-separated strings."

Comment: Can you not do ... readarray -t arr <<< "$(echo '{"crew":[{"name":"kirk"},{"name":"bones"},{"name":"mr spock"}]}' | jq '.crew[].name')"

Comment: @RamanSailopal yes, `readarray` seems to work. Thank you. However, I am still interested to know why bash seems to remove/ignore the quotes that jq is wrapping the values in.

Comment: @JonHudson See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables) (it's about a different situation, but the word-splitting process is exactly the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
$ ary=($(echo '{"crew":[{"name":"kirk"},{"name":"bones"},{"name":"mr spock"}]}' | jq -r '.crew[].name | @sh'))
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary=([0]="'kirk'" [1]="'bones'" [2]="'mr" [3]="spock'")
```

This does not work as expected because the command substitution is unquoted, bash will perform word splitting on the output. It doesn't matter that the actual output contains quote characters. Refer to [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) in the manual

You need to delay the array assignment until the contents of the output can be examined by the shell. This *could* be done with `eval`, but for variable assignment it's better done with `declare`:

```sh
$ declare -a "ary=($(echo '{"crew":[{"name":"kirk"},{"name":"bones"},{"name":"mr spock"}]}' | jq -r '.crew[].name | @sh'))"
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary=([0]="kirk" [1]="bones" [2]="mr spock")
```

For readability, split that into steps:

```sh
$ jq_out=$(echo '{"crew":[{"name":"kirk"},{"name":"bones"},{"name":"mr spock"}]}' | jq -r '.crew[].name | @sh')
$ declare -a "ary=( $jq_out )"
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary=([0]="kirk" [1]="bones" [2]="mr spock")
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me understand why it was happening. I didn't know quote removal was a thing https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal I think however that for simplicity and because I understand it more, I will use the `readarray` solution above.

Answer (score 2):

If your bash does not support mapfile/readarray, you could use the idiom illustrated by the following:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION

while read -r name ; do
    ary+=("$name")
done < <(echo '{"crew":[{"name":"kirk"},{"name":"bones"},{"name":"mr spock"}]}' |
   jq -r '.crew[].name')

declare -p ary
```

Output

```
3.2.57(1)-release
declare -a ary='([0]="kirk" [1]="bones" [2]="mr spock")'
```

Notice in particular that

- `$name` is quoted in the array-update line
- there is no need to use `@sh`, which indeed in this case is probably not what you want.

Of course, if the JSON strings might contain embedded new lines, then the above would have to be tweaked accordingly, e.g. to use NUL (`"\u0000"`) as the delimiter.

Comment: You'll want to use `IFS= read -r name` -- that will read the line exactly verbatim. Without `IFS=` then leading/trailing whitespace will be removed.